# How to find last " | " character of description

Tags: android, regex

Let us suppose I have these descriptions like those below. I want fetch the description with the ending character `|`. How can I do this?

Description Model 1:

> Whether or not Nicki Minaj deserved to receive a VMA nomination for “Anaconda” is irrelevant. The fact remains that the video broke a Vevo record for the most views in a single day, became a pop cultural phenomenon within the past year, and is now immortalized with a Minaj | wax figure at Madame Tussauds

Result model 1 should be:

> Whether or not Nicki Minaj deserved to receive a VMA nomination for “Anaconda” is irrelevant. The fact remains that the video broke a Vevo record for the most views in a single day, became a pop cultural phenomenon within the past year, and is now immortalized with a Minaj |

Description Model 2:

> घटनापछि बालिकाको मानसिक अवस्था ठिक नभएको र उपचार भइरहेको उनले बताइन् । महिला तथा बालबालिका टोल सुधार समितिका कोषाध्यक्ष रचना श्रेष्ठले अपराध गर्नेलाई कुनै पनि सर्तमा छाड्न नहुने बताइन् । कुचबाडियालाई प्रहरीले नियन्त्रणमा लिएर अनुसन्धान अघि बढाएको बाँके प्रहरी

Result model 2 should be:

> घटनापछि बालिकाको मानसिक अवस्था ठिक नभएको र उपचार भइरहेको उनले बताइन् । महिला तथा बालबालिका टोल सुधार समितिका कोषाध्यक्ष रचना श्रेष्ठले अपराध गर्नेलाई कुनै पनि सर्तमा छाड्न नहुने बताइन् ।

Comment: How are you extracting the descriptions? Regular expressions? please show us the code you have.

Comment: There is `"asdsad | asdasd | asddsa".lastIndexOf("|")`

Comment: get the character at the end of the description and check with your special character  | whether it matches or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the string like this:

```
String newstr = "";
if (null != str && str.length() > 0 )
{
    int endIndex1 = str.lastIndexOf("|");
    int endIndex2 = str.lastIndexOf("।");
    if (endIndex1 > endIndex2)  
    {
        newstr = str.substring(0, endIndex1); 
    }else if(endIndex2 != -1) {
        newstr = str.substring(0, endIndex2);
    }
}
```

Comment: this results -1

Log.i("END_POINT", String.valueOf(endIndex));

Comment: Oh yeah it's working with the model no 1 but with the model no 2 it's not working and results -1.

Comment: Yup it's working. Would you mind telling me where is that small " | " character in the keyword.

Comment: I don't think there is a character like that in my Hungarian keyboard. I have copied it from your post :)